# CSS Border overlap between two cells in table

Tags: javascript, html, css

how to add border for filename3 and filename4 column as a whole using html and css.

[table with borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBtFS.png)

```html
   
   <table>
   <tbody>
    <td id="filename1"> 1</td>
    <td id="filename2">1 </td>
    <td id="filename3"> 1</td>
    <td id="filename4"> 1</td> 
    </tbody>    
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give both cells a border, then remove the border on one side with the `border-right` and `border-left` properties:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#filename3 {
  border: 10px solid;
  border-right: 0px;
}

#filename4 {
  border: 10px solid;
  border-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td id="filename1">1</td>
  <td id="filename2">2</td>
  <td id="filename3">3</td>
  <td id="filename4">4</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to select both of the ID's at the same time? You can select both of the IDs by

```
#filename3, #filename4 {/*enter css styles here*/}
```

If you are trying to select both by a single class, simply add a parent div around the 2 elements you are trying to group.

```
<tbody><td id="filename1"> </td><td id="filename2"> </td><div class='parent'><td id="filename3"> </td><td id="filename4"> </td></div></tbody>
```

Hope this helped :)!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
<style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
</style>
```

Html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
        <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">sum: 180</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Have you tried this colspan attribute? If this is what you asked.